# Changing BaseURL of TParseApi class from main unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Since Parse has discontinued its service I need to move to a third-party hosted Parse solution for push notifications (I'd like to stick to the Parse environment). The default `BaseURL` used by `TParseApi` is defined as :

```
public const
  ...
  cDefaultBaseURL = 'https://api.parse.com/{ApiVersion}';
```

Within the `TParseApi` class exists a public property called `BaseURL` which is set to `cDefaultBaseURL` in `TParseApi.Create()` and with which one can otherwise set the base URL used for the REST calls. This needs to be changed to the new hosted server's address instead of the old discontinued Parse service's address.

In my main unit I am only creating and working with the `TPushEvents` and `TParseProvider` objects. I would like to change the `BaseURL` property of `TParseApi` from within my main unit at runtime to the new address, but I cannot find a way to get access to the `TParseApi` object from my main unit. I would rather not change the constant value in the `REST.Backend.ParseApi` unit, because I would have to keep maintaining my own version of that unit indefinitely.

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Can someone please help me to figure out how to get access to the `TParseApi` object from my main unit, or alternatively create a replacement `TParseApi` object of my own in the main unit and then get `TParseProvider`/`TPushEvents` to use mine instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
type
  TMyPushEvents = class(TPushEvents)
  public
    property BackendService: IBackendPushDeviceService read GetBackendService;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIntf: IGetParseAPI;
  LParseAPI: TParseAPI;
begin
  if Supports(TMyPushEvents(PushEvents1).BackendService, IGetParseAPI, LIntf) then
  begin
    LParseAPI := LIntf.ParseAPI;
    LParseAPI.BaseURL := 'http://new.url';
  end;
end;
```